# Why does `count` plus faster than I rotate the phone last time?

Tags: android

Here is the `MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName() ;
private Handler handler;
private static int count = 0;
private TextView tv;
private long current = 0;

private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG,(System.currentTimeMillis()-current)+" has passed since last called.");
            Log.d(TAG,"r Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            count++;
            Log.d(TAG,"count is now :"+count);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"Oncreate called!");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();
    Log.d(TAG,"UI Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        tv.setText(""+savedInstanceState.getInt("count"));
    }
    current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    handler.postDelayed(r,2000);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onSavedInstance called!");
    outState.putInt("count",count);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,"Onresume called!");
    }
}
```

the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

It is a very simple Android Handler test demo, I just want to increase count with 1 every 1 second. But when I rotate the phone, the `tv` textview actually displays like `2 4 6 8 10`,when I again roate the phone, it displays like `2 5 8 11 14`, and again like `2 6 10 14 18` and go on.But from the log-cat, every time count is plused with 1 every time, but not in one second.Why?

Answer (score 0):

> But from the log-cat, every time count is plused with 1 every time,
>   but not in one second.Why?

Because whenever you rotate your `activity` create one extra `handler` and they increasing your value for every seconds like first time it was working good but after rotate it was increasing with 2 and another rotate it will increasing with 3 and so on.

Note:- Every Time your rotate your program creating new `handler`.

Solution:- To overcome this problem you have to reset your `handler` on every rotate means your have to finish your last handler and start new one. Use this `override` method of `Activity` `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`

Read this [onConfigrationChange](https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a)

Android Configuration Change [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

Use below override methods in your `Activity` and it will solve your problem.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // use this method if you have to do functionality on Portrait or Landscape 
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("lastValue", count);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt("lastValue");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The handler is started in `onCreate` so it should be stopped in `onDestroy`, use method: `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`.

If you wont do it you might suffer crashes after navigating out from this activity due to handler which tries to updated destroyed view.